# How to access elements inside a list and store them as new columns in the dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, list, tuples

I have the following dataframe

df

| keywords |
| --- |
| [(caused patient, 0.4807), (wa non, 0.1332), (2021, -0.0076)] |
| [(incorrect reconstitution, 0.9084), (error, 0.5304), (incorrect, 0.2877)] |

The column name is keywords which needs to be split by the "," and new columns have to be generated like: keyword_1, keyword_2, keyword_3

so my df should look like

Expected Dataframe

| keyword_1 | keyword_2 | keyword_3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| (caused patient, 0.4807) | (wa non, 0.1332) | (2021, -0.0076) |
| (incorrect reconstitution, 0.9084) | (error, 0.5304) | (incorrect, 0.2877) |

I tried the following:

`new_col_list = ['first_keyword', 'second_keyword',`
`'third_keyword']`
`for n,col in enumerate(new_col_list):`
`df[col] = df['keywords'].apply(lambda keywords: keywords[n])`

`df = df('keywords',axis=1)`

but it throws me the error: **IndexError: list index out of range**

How do I achieve my expected dataframe?

Answer (score 0):

Here's your solution:

```
new_df = pd.DataFrame(columns=[f"keywords_{i+1}" for i in range(len(df["Keywords"].iloc[0]))])
    
for row_idx, col in enumerate(df['Keywords']):
    new_df.loc[row_idx] = col

print(new_df)
```

Output:

```
                            keyword_1         keyword_2            keyword_3
0            (caused patient, 0.4807)  (wa non, 0.1332)      (2021, -0.0076)
1  (incorrect reconstitution, 0.9084)   (error, 0.5304)  (incorrect, 0.2877)
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option:

```
df[['keyword1', 'keyword2', 'keyword3']] = pd.DataFrame(df['keywords'].tolist(), index=df.index)


print(df)




                           keyword1          keyword2             keyword3  
0            (caused patient, 0.4807)  (wa non, 0.1332)      (2021, -0.0076)  
1  (incorrect reconstitution, 0.9084)   (error, 0.5304)  (incorrect, 0.2877)
```

Comment: This is a hard-coded solution, considering if the entries of the original DataFrame varies

Comment: @MusabbirArrafi: Then will add the new column names. Loop is not a good option. If you have 1M row data, then your code will run for ages.